# is upload base64_decode image via file put content secure?

Tags: php, image-resizing

I'm following code in http://www.codeforest.net/html5-image-upload-resize-and-crop , after resize at client side, it save using `file_put_contents($file, $data);`.

```
if ($_POST) {
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
    $img = $_POST['image'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpg';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
}
```

however I donno how this function actually work, what I'm worried is - if the user changed the hidden input field of and fake php code to look like images, or user changed hidden input field with another image of difference size, what will be the best practice to prevent this from happening?

Comment: best practice: don't use form fields for data that you don't want the user to tamper with. Use session variables.

Comment: it is resize via client size, how to use session data?

Comment: I was assuming the hidden field was created by another PHP script. If you have to get data created by the client, then you need to validate it. Use `getimagesize` after writing the image to a file.

Answer (score 1):

After writing the data to the file, use `getimagesize()` to validate that it's proper image data. If this fails, delete the file and report a failed upload.

Comment: is the image secure from virus written in php carried in a jpeg image?

Comment: Probably not. Unless you can find an anti-virus class to use in PHP. I  said in my comment, don't take data from the user if you can avoid it.

Comment: its an avatar image and I have to do it. Was using GD to copy image in server side however donno how to script it after it was resized to base64_decode